# Webscraping code failing on similar pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Title

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
from random import randint


theurl = "http://ufcstats.com/event-details/7abe471b61725980"

r=requests.get(theurl)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
Name=soup.find(class_='b-fight-details__table-body')
Name=Name.text.strip()
links=soup.find_all('a')

# print(links)
Fighter = []
for link in links:
    href=link['href']
    if href:
        print(href)
        if r'fighter-details' in href:
            Fighter.append(href)
            print(Fighter)
```

Works perfectly for old events:

http://ufcstats.com/event-details/6f812143641ceff8

But not a new event?

http://ufcstats.com/event-details/7abe471b61725980

I get the following error:

```
    return self.attrs[key]
           ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 'href'
```

But there the same webpage? Why does [href] give me an error, its clearly there in the 'a' tag, I tried to strip out the text from the a tag, but doesn't seem to want to work either.

Comment: How does it "not work"? Can you share what happens for the second case in the question, and what is surprising about that? (we could just run the code and see for ourselves, but that doesn't help anyone who only has the question and answer to look at)

Comment: The same base URL does not mean the same page.  A content management system is free to change ass much as it wants.  View source, save source, compare the files.  A differencing or file compare plugin for your text editor can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the table there are links without the `href=` attribute so your script fails. One way to fix it is to use `dict.get()` with default value:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = "http://ufcstats.com/event-details/7abe471b61725980"
soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get(theurl).text,'html.parser')

Name=soup.find(class_='b-fight-details__table-body')
links=Name.find_all('a')

Fighter = []
for link in links:
    href=link.get('href', '')  # <-- get href= attribute or empty string if the attribute doesn't exist
    if href:
        if 'fighter-details' in href:
            Fighter.append(href)

print(*Fighter, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/853eb0dd5c0e2149
http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/6d35bf94f7d30241
http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/7aa3d6964eff4877
http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/361d49960a196976
http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/d1941565abf50b16
http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/7026eca45f65377b

...and so on.
```